# Passende Einleitung für einen Brief

Tags: usage

Ich möchte einen Brief für zwei meiner Freunde schreiben. Was ist die richtige, bessere und höfliche Einleitung?

> Liebe Rita und Frank,
>
> Liebe Rita und lieber Frank,
>
> Liebe Rita, lieber Frank,

Comment: Die 3. Variante

Answer (score 12, accepted):

"Liebe Rita, lieber Frank," ist richtig und am häufigsten verwendet.

Die erste Variante setzt voraus, dass Frank entweder

- weiblich ist ("Liebe ..." bezieht sich auf beide Namen) oder
- nicht lieb ist.

Comment: "Meine Damen und Herren, und Frank" ;)

Comment: Wenn es eine Frau statt Frank gibt, kann ich einmal `Liebe` bringen oder es ist nicht häufig?

Comment: Grammatikalisch wäre es dann korrekt, dennoch würde man für jede Person "liebe..." voranstellen.
Um zu lange Aufzählungen zu vermeiden, kann man auch gruppieren ("Liebe Nachbarn"). Das wirkt allerdings leicht unpersönlicher.

Comment: @Vogel612 Vor "und" kommt kein Komma :p

Comment: _Liebe Rita und Frank_ ist durchaus nicht unüblich, wenn Rita und Frank ein gemeinsam angesprochenes Paar sind. _Liebe_ steht dann im geschlechtslosen Plural und nicht im Femininum.

Answer (score 3):

> Liebe Rita, lieber Frank,

passt am besten.

Answer (score 1):

#3 is the way to go.

> Liebe Rita und Frank

doesn't work because Frank is male. If you must use something like this,

> Lieber(r) Rita und Frank

could work, but it's not exactly good style. (Reminds me of "Dear occupant" letters.)